# Insert values into table with procedure

Tags: sql-server, procedure

I tried to implement procedure which main goal is to store data into separate table.I order to do this first I started with simple query with scalar variables. Below you can see code:

```
DECLARE @CustomerId int=8
DECLARE @validFrom date='2019.01.01'
DECLARE @ValidTo date='2019.03.01'
DECLARE @EmployeeID int=8
SELECT  CONCAT(c.FirstName, ' ', c.LastName) AS CustomerFullName, lo.Name as LocationName,acd.Amount,cu.Name as Currency,acc.EmployeeId,@validFrom as ValidFrom,@ValidTo as ValidTo,CONCAT(emp.FirstName, ' ', emp.LastName) AS EmployeeFullName
FROM dbo.Customer as c
INNER JOIN dbo.Account AS acc ON acc.CurrencyId=c.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.AccountDetails AS acd ON acd.AccountId=acc.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.Currency AS cu ON cu.id=acc.CurrencyId
INNER JOIN dbo.Location as lo ON lo.Id=acd.LocationId
INNER JOIN dbo.Employee AS emp ON emp.ID=acc.EmployeeId
WHERE acc.CustomerId=@CustomerId and acd.TransactionDate between @validFrom and @ValidTo and acc.EmployeeId=@EmployeeID
```

So code above works great and give me expect results.

So next step is to put this code into procedure in order to filling table with data from procedure.For that reason I make table and also I try to put code above into procedure

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerReportLogs (
    ID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    CustomerFullName NVARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL,
    LocationName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Amount decimal (18,2) NOT NULL,
    Currency NVARCHAR (20)NOT NULL,
    EmployeeId int NOT NULL,
    ValidFrom date NOT NULL,
    ValidTo date NOT NULL,
    EmployeeFullName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ID_CustomerReportLogs PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    ID ASC
    ))
    GO


CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.procedure1 (@CustomerId int, @validFrom date, @ValidTo date,@EmployeeID int)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT  CONCAT(c.FirstName, ' ', c.LastName) AS CustomerFullName, lo.Name as LocationName,acd.Amount,cu.Name as Currency,acc.EmployeeId,@validFrom as ValidFrom,@ValidTo as ValidTo,CONCAT(emp.FirstName, ' ', emp.LastName) AS EmployeeFullName
FROM dbo.Customer as c
INNER JOIN dbo.Account AS acc ON acc.CurrencyId=c.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.AccountDetails AS acd ON acd.AccountId=acc.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.Currency AS cu ON cu.id=acc.CurrencyId
INNER JOIN dbo.Location as lo ON lo.Id=acd.LocationId
INNER JOIN dbo.Employee AS emp ON emp.ID=acc.EmployeeId
WHERE acc.CustomerId=@CustomerId and acd.TransactionDate between @validFrom and @ValidTo and acc.EmployeeId=@EmployeeID
SELECT *
INSERT INTO dbo.CustomerReportLogs(CustomerFullName,LocationName,Amount,Currency,EmployeeId,ValidFrom,ValidTo,EmployeeFullName)
VALUES (@CustomerFullName,@LocationName,@Amount,@Currency,@EmployeeId,@ValidFrom,@ValidTo,@EmployeeFullName)
Return
END
GO
```

Error message from above procedure is that I need to declare scalar variable @CustomerFullName,but this variable actually I got from code with concat function and is not scalar. So probably in last part of my code I have some errors. So can anybody help me how to fix this errors?

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure procedure1, Line 29 [Batch Start Line 3767]
Must declare the scalar variable "@CustomerFullName".
```

Comment: what do you exactly by `My intention is to have procedure which can automatically use input parameters and fill table with output` ?

Comment: I want to use above procedure with this command and get results e.g EXEC dbo.procedure1  @CustomerId=8,@validFrom='2019.01.25', @ValidTo='2019.03.01', @EmployeeID=8

Comment: So you don't want to insert into table `CustomerReportLogs` ? Then just remove that `insert into CustomerReportLogs` line

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually storing your returned values in variables. You could do that I.e. you first declare the variables and then use something like `SELECT @CustomerFullName = CONCAT(c.FirstName, ' ', c.LastName) .... FROM ...` , but far easier would be to replace your SELECT directly with the INSERT. I.e.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.procedure1 (@CustomerId int, @validFrom date, @ValidTo date,@EmployeeID int)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.CustomerReportLogs(
        CustomerFullName
        , LocationName
        , Amount
        , Currency
        , EmployeeId
        , ValidFrom
        , ValidTo
        , EmployeeFullName
    )
    SELECT  
        CONCAT(c.FirstName, ' ', c.LastName) AS CustomerFullName
        , lo.Name as LocationName
        , acd.Amount
        , cu.Name as Currency
        , acc.EmployeeId
        , @validFrom as ValidFrom
        , @ValidTo as ValidTo
        , CONCAT(emp.FirstName, ' ', emp.LastName) AS EmployeeFullName
    FROM 
        dbo.Customer as c
        INNER JOIN dbo.Account AS acc ON acc.CurrencyId=c.Id
        INNER JOIN dbo.AccountDetails AS acd ON acd.AccountId=acc.Id
        INNER JOIN dbo.Currency AS cu ON cu.id=acc.CurrencyId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Location as lo ON lo.Id=acd.LocationId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Employee AS emp ON emp.ID=acc.EmployeeId
    WHERE 
        acc.CustomerId = @CustomerId 
        AND acd.TransactionDate BETWEEN @validFrom AND @ValidTo 
        AND acc.EmployeeId = @EmployeeID
END
```

Please note this has not been tested, but I just copy/pasted your own code

Comment: My intention is to have procedure which can automatically use input parameters and fill table with output. Above code is only for insert values into table and not include procedure

Comment: @silent_hunter I'm not sure I follow. I edited my code to include your stored procedure declaration. The end result is the exact same thing, though. It uses the parameters `@CustomerID`, `@ValidFrom`, `@ValidTo`, and `@EmployeeID` to perform the `INSERT`, just as your original code does. I merely skip the part where you do a `SELECT`, because it's not necessary.

Comment: @silent_hunter Is the issue that you expect something to be returned by the stored procedure?